# Disable Browsers Basic-Authentication Popup by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, basic-authentication

I know that every browser reacts in a different way and that the behaviour can change with new versions.

I am trying to find a way to disable the basic-authentication dialog of chrome and IE, because I want to handle it on my own in an JavaScript (AngularJS) client. I found [this nice module](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-http-auth), with this the popup is not shown in Firefox, but in chrome and IE it still is shown.

I would like to handle it in JavaScript. There seems to be a common way to let the server send not a HTTP 401 status code, but instead another (e.g. HTTP 418), but I don't like this approach, because then the services can not easily be tested with a browser. Also, I think when the server does not send the `'WWW-Authenticate'='Basic realm=test'` header, the *Basic-Authentication* popup is not shown.

As I stated before, it would be nice to have it handled by JavaScript.